# How do I get the key name of a Hashtable object passed to a function in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have this test setup:

```
[PSObject]$Obj = @{}

$Obj.add("Obj1", @{A="1"; B="2"})

$Obj.add("Obj2", @{A="3"; B="4"})

function Test-Function ([PSObject]$O) {
    $O
}

Test-Function $Obj["Obj1"]
```

In the function Test-Function I would like to get the name of the key of O$ (in this case Obj1) like:

```
O$.Key
```

but I can't find a property for this. I have tried to find it with:

```
$O | Get-Member
$O.PSObject
$O.PSObject | Get-Member
```

but no luck and I can't find another post about it.

I know I can just change it to:

```
$Obj.add("Obj1", @{ID="Obj1"; A="1"; B="2"})
```

but that seems redundant.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks :-)

Comment: the reason there is no key when running `Test-Function $Obj["Obj1"]` is that you request the value of the key you pass (which is "Obj1"). if you know what key you are requesting then why do you need it returned?

Comment: Thanks, good point and you are right. The moment I call the function I know it is e.g. Obj1, but within the function I do not know that and this is where I actually need it for further processing.

I hope this explanation makes sense :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so with your comment that you need the obj within the function i edited your example to the following. the function now takes the object and the key as two parameters. that way you can work with the key further more within the function.

```
[PSObject]$Obj = @{}
$Obj.add("Obj1", @{A="1"; B="2"})
$Obj.add("Obj2", @{A="3"; B="4"})

function Test-Function ($object, $key) {
    $object[$key]
    Write-Host $key
}

Test-Function -object $Obj -key "Obj1"
```

Comment: Hmmm, this will actually fulfil my needs - Thank you very much  :-)